Stepper motor driver connector identification
I want to use this driver for some stepper motors.

Problem is that the stepper motors simply have the loose cables so I am trying to find the pin connectors. The guide Common JST Connector Types was really helpful, but it's not useful unless I know what the female ones on the driver are. Unfortunately, I cannot find that anywhere.
So, is there is a guide somewhere to figure out the pin connectors?
What are these connectors?

The driver ones are male. But no, there is no de jure /standard/. There might be common choices in certain application areas though

Do you have a link for the driver board?  That's where we'd usually look for definition of which connectors it used.

If you bought that module, you should have received documentation about it, or at least read it on the web page. This documentation should have provided you what connector the board uses and what connector should be used to connect to it. You should ask the seller.

There aren't standards for all connectors. Usually if you have the pitch and dimensions you can do a digikey search and find a match

Instead of asking "What are the standards for cable connectors?", you should ask: "What is this connector?" I know the answer, but I am not allowed to answer once a question is closed. Instead, let me point you to you a place where you can ask: https://old.reddit.com/r/ElectricalEngineering/ (I have no association with that subreddit.) If you ask there, I'll tell you the answer.

I edited the title to be identifying these connectors, which is surely on-topic.

@jonathanjo Thank you for the edit. I voted to reopen.

That is a JST XH connector, 2.5 mm pitch.
